# Comma separated string split by length but keeping the comma separation?

Tags: arrays, string, split

I have a string like this `"105321,102305,321506,0321561,3215658"` and i need to split this string by the comma (`,`) and with a specific length, so if the length of each string part is `15`, the splited array must be like:

```
105321,102305
321506,0321561
3215658
```

I try several ways but i can't find the right approach to do this

The code that i have gives me an error of index out of range:

```
private static List<string> SplitThis(char charToSplit, string text, int maxSplit)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        string[] firstSplit = text.Split(charToSplit);
        for(int i = 0; i < firstSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            string part = firstSplit[i];
            if(output.Any() && output[i].Length + part.Length >= maxSplit)
            {
                output.Add(part);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!output.Any())
                    output.Add(part);
                else
                    output[i] += "," + part;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Edit: i must say that the comma `,` must be a part of the amount of the maxSplit variable.

Comment: Just paste your several ways and we will let you know what's wrong.

Comment: The problem is that every way i try is not finished because i cant figure out how to do it

Comment: that's ok. paste your code...

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
 private static List<string> SplitThis(char charToSplit, string text, int maxSplit)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        string[] firstSplit = text.Split(charToSplit);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < firstSplit.Length)
        {
            string part = firstSplit[i];
            while (part.Length < maxSplit)
            {
                if (part.Length < maxSplit && i + 1 < firstSplit.Length)
                {
                    if ((part + "," + firstSplit[i + 1]).Length < maxSplit)
                    {
                        part += "," + firstSplit[i + 1];
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Add(part);
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(part);
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: That method repeats lines. Tested with: `string p = "105321,102305,321506,0321561,3215658,321568789,3215"` and `SplitThis(',',p, 27);`

Comment: @Phoenix_uy I'm sorry I made a mistake it works correctly now

Answer (score 0):

This one would be concise, yet not really performant

```
private static Pattern P = Pattern.compile("(.{1,15})(,|$)");

private static String[] split(String string) {
    Matcher m = P.matcher(string);
    List<String> splits = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        splits.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return splits.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

The regular expression in P matches `(.{1,15})(,|$)`:

- a sequence of 1 to 15 characters = `.{1,15}`
- followed by `,` or line ending
- the parentheses allow grouping, the content of the first group is what you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string originalString = "105321,102305,321506,0321561,3215658";
    string[] commaSplit = originalString.Split(',');
    string tempString = string.Empty;
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < commaSplit.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ((tempString.Length + commaSplit[i].Length) > 15)
        {
            result.Add(tempString);
            tempString = string.Empty;
        }

        if (tempString.Length > 0)
        {
            tempString += ',' + commaSplit[i];
        }
        else
        {
            tempString += commaSplit[i];
        }

        if (i == commaSplit.Length - 1 && tempString != string.Empty)
        {
            result.Add(tempString);
        }
    }

    foreach (var s in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This may not be the best solution but it works ;)